# Rewriting URLs from old website

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an old website that uses links such as:
**www.oldsite.com/pages.asp?pageid=123456**

And have a new website that uses links such as: **newsite.com/about**

The old site appears in search results like that and I need to rewrite the owld URLs to the new site. I have searched for hours and hours and tried multiple things (none have exactly matched my situation) concerning RewriteRules and such and none have worked. I'm using

```
redirect  /pages.asp /
```

now as a temporary solution, but I need the various links in search results to go to the new location (as in *...id=12345* goes to */about*).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You!

**Clarification:**

The old website is completely out of my control, it is 301 redirecting to the new site. So the actual URLs I want to redirect are in the form **newsite.com/pages.asp?pageid=123456**.
I want to redirect the old pages to matching new pages. Some Examples:

**www.newsite.com/pages.asp?pageid=123456**  >>  **newsite.com/about**

**www.newsite.com/pages.asp?pageid=85544**  >>  **newsite.com/contact**

Comment: Do you want all requests to `/pages.asp` (not depending on `pageid` value) to redirect to `/about` new website page ? Is your server (old website) an *Apache* server ? Do you have **mod_alias** (to use `Redirect`) or **mod_rewrite** (to use `RewriteRule`) enabled ?

Comment: @JustinIurman I edited the question to clarify. I'm not sure that mod_alias and mod_rewrite are enabled since the server is hosted and I can't access that information. But Joomla is installed and working normally and I am able to use Redirect.

Comment: Do you have more urls with `pageid` to redirect ? Because you'll have to write a specific rule for each case (or use a `RewriteMap`)

Comment: There are about 10 pages to redirect. I just need a template to write all the Rules or make the Map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only 10 pages, you can do it with simple rules instead of a map.

You can put this code in your htaccess (which has to be in root folder)

```
RewriteEngine On

# example rule for "about"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pageid=123456$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^pages\.asp$ /about? [R=301,L]

# example rule for "contact"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pageid=85544$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^pages\.asp$ /contact? [R=301,L]

# and so on for your other pages ID...
```

Comment: Ahh, I was so close! Thank You! One thing though, is there a way to remove the '?pageid=85544' from the rewritten URL?

Comment: My bad, i forgot that. You just have to add a `?` after name pages. You can try my edited answer. You'll have to clear your browser's cache to see the new rules working because old rules are in cache now